# How to run typeorm mysql commands from sql file?

Tags: mysql, nestjs, typeorm

I would like to run mysql commands in a migration from an sql file. Can somebody help me, how to solve it?

```js
import {MigrationInterface, QueryRunner} from "typeorm";
import * as fs from "fs";

var queries = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/geoinfo.sql').toString()
    .replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm," ") // remove newlines
    .replace(/\s+/g, ' '); // excess white space

export class HungarianStatesAndCities1564393283405 implements MigrationInterface {

    public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<any> {
        await queryRunner.query(queries.toString() );
    }

    public async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<any> {
        await queryRunner.query("");
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like it could be a solution that would work. What seems to be the issue?

Comment: It is not working. Anyone have a workable solution? It fails with syntax error, but in the file the code is fine.

Comment: What is the error? Like I said, the code looks correct enough, but without knowing **what** specifically is happening when you try to run the script it won't be possible to help.

Answer (score 4):

you can use split queries by ';' and run individual query

```
const readSqlFile = (filepath: string): string[] => {
      return fs
        .readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, filepath))
        .toString()
        .replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, '')
        .split(';')
        .filter((query) => query?.length);
    };

public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
    const queries = readSqlFile('/geoinfo.sql');

    for (let i = 0; i < queries.length; i++) {
      await queryRunner.query(queries[i]);
    }
  }
```

Comment: `.split(';')` does not take into account insert statements which may include a semi-colon in the data. A better solution would be to split by semi-colons which are followed by a line-break (assuming the sql file has line breaks after each statement):

`.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, '\n').split(';\n')`

Answer (score -1):

Wrapped into the library at npm. Now you can include it in your project easily.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sql-reader

Comment: doesn't work for functions

Comment: @mcjkwlczk You mean you want to create a stored procedure?